# Firefox - all form buttons blank

Tags: firefox

While debugging an extension I was creating, all of the form buttons on a page have gone blank. Any idea how to solve this?

I've cleared my cache and everything. I even tried disabling all my addons and plugins but to no avail.

[alt text http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/7765/picblank.png](http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/7765/picblank.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried re-installing Firefox?

Comment: Very funny. Its only on the profile I use for development. Any site on my other profile works fine.

Comment: I don't get how that is a joke. It seems like the obvious answer based on your question. Have you tried creating a new profile to use for development? If you can reproduce the problem you might find the cause.